# Safari Books Online on Kindle Paperwhite experimental Browser

Tags: kindle, kindle-paperwhite

This questions if for someone with a subscription in https://www.safaribooksonline.com and a Kindle Paperwhite, Does is it possible to read a book from safari books online on the browser of the Kindle Paperwhite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I have tried and it works.

The login process is the same as in any web browser. Navigation within the site is a little difficult but book reading is quite good. However, I couldn't increase font size, but symbols and text were rendered perfectly.

They need to launch some optimized site for Kindle at least.